# Android Studio - App crashes on device but not on Emulator - Probably Missing Permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im currently working on an App that reads multiple folders and displays them in 3 Tabs with a listview. The app works without a problem on the Emulated Device but crashes on my normal Device.

This is the output I get when I launch the app on my device.

```
09/02 12:05:03: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi MI 9 Transparent Edition.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.stundenzettel2/com.example.stundenzettel2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 9449 on device 'xiaomi-mi_9_transparent_edition-331b53a7'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: name expected (position:START_TAG <dimen name='config_icon_width'>@7:32 in java.io.InputStreamReader@f9d92f) 
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:147)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeValues.parseThemeValues(ThemeValues.java:123)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeResources$LoadThemeConfigHelper.load(ThemeResources.java:443)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeZipFile.loadThemeConfigInner(ThemeZipFile.java:272)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeZipFile.loadThemeConfig(ThemeZipFile.java:254)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeResources$LoadThemeConfigHelper.newTarget(ThemeResources.java:436)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeResources.loadThemeValues(ThemeResources.java:455)
W/System.err:     at miui.content.res.ThemeResources.checkUpdate(ThemeResources.java:225)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeResourcesSystem.checkUpdate(ThemeResourcesSystem.java:76)
        at miui.content.res.ThemeResources.getSystem(ThemeResources.java:123)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.updateConfiguration(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:248)
        at android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1970)
        at android.content.res.Resources.updateSystemConfiguration(Resources.java:1983)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ResourcesManager.java:1048)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/FeatureParser: can't find cepheus.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
W/.stundenzettel2: type=1400 audit(0.0:115384): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=28839 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c175,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.stundenzettel2
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.stundenzettel2
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
W/.stundenzettel: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/.stundenzettel: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.tab1.<init>(tab1.java:165)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.PageAdapter.getItem(PageAdapter.java:25)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:170)
W/System.err:     at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1784)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.tab2.<init>(tab2.java:44)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.PageAdapter.getItem(PageAdapter.java:31)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:170)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1784)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7787)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.tab3.<init>(tab3.java:44)
        at com.example.stundenzettel2.PageAdapter.getItem(PageAdapter.java:37)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:170)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1784)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stundenzettel2, PID: 9449
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.doAddOp(FragmentTransaction.java:161)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:179)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.add(FragmentTransaction.java:156)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:172)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6885)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24603)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1784)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I think I`m getting a NullPointerException because the App cant read the files inside my device.
This is propably the Problem. Im trying to get the files from the folder and create a file in the folder so that it cant be empty.

```
public tab1() throws IOException {

        final File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        System.out.println(path);

        File f = new File(path + "/My Files/Angefangen");

        File b = new File(path + "/My Files/Angefangen/bruh.txt");
        b.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        b.createNewFile();

        accepted = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
    }
```

[Codeblock as Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB5HZ.png)

My Manifest has the Permission Lines added and im asking for permission in my MainActivity i dont know if thats enough.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };


    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Fixed it by adding this to the Manifest for Devices above API 29.

```
<manifest ... > 
 
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
</application></manifest>
```

Comment: 1-Change properties of your emulator and try get the same exception

Comment: 1-Change properties of your emulator and try get the same exception 2-Check all properties of your emulator with your real device.If you use internet check the internet connection of your app for exceptions. The capacity of your device also may be a subject for this issue.Try to empty your device.In every case run your app without debugging in your real device.If after it your issue is removed then you have memory issue in your device and use  booster ram apps for free up ...

Comment: @maniaq Okay i recreated the Error on the Emulator but im not sure how that helped me. It probably means that the App is incompatible with my phone. Im still getting the permission denied error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was fixed by adding this to the Manifest for Devices with an API of 29 and above.

```
<manifest ... >  
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
...
</application></manifest>
```